# clear cell value if condition is met vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use pivot table to generate charts but then I wanted to incorporate vba codes to clear values if certain string is selected, so I don't want to generate charts if certain string is selected.

Now, my vba codes uses a lot of lookup functions which I should incorporate the iferror statement back then but again I feel like its too late for me to go back and will just take more time to fix each vlookup function I used. Now, since I am only getting stuck on this portion, I am just going to post the codes for this portion.

How pivot table and charts work is that the user selects zip code and/or county and it will calculate vlaues and graph will appear so I can monitor monthly data. Each of the 3 selection button has N/A which is supposed to not return any value so chart won't graph, similar to reset button. I just tested if I select zipcode as N/A but the codes failed so I haven't expanded my test codes to county and territory. Also (All) is different from N/A as for (All), I am calculating everything, as the whole book of business.

I tried to copy and paste the pivot table as values and see if it will work, and it just won't execute, and when I pressed **F8**, it looks like it skips the range selection and selection.clearcontents part and jumps to the end.

[image]

```
Sub test()

'take out n/a
Dim find As String

find = "N/A"

Select Case find
    Case Cells(2, 2).Value = find
        Range("E14:R14").Select
        Range("E43:R43").Select
        Range("E73:R73").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: `Case Cells(2, 2).Value = find` is either `True` or `False`.  If you want to check for `"N/A"`, remove the comparison.  `Select Case find` does it for you:  `Case Cells(2, 2).Value`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a easy fix.